# How to prevent concurrent access in SpringBoot restcontroller

Tags: spring-boot

If while executing one rest method, at the same time came next request also so I need to prevent the second request and respond back "One person is already using". How to achieve this in spring boot? I tried the code below given. But it's not request rejected. Its added into a queue, after first request second one will execute.

```
@RestController
class TestController {

 private static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

 @GetMapping("tests")
 public String get() {
   System.err.println("----------------------------------------1 " + lock.isLocked());
   if (!lock.tryLock()) {
     System.err.println("--------------------------------------2 " + lock.isLocked());
     return "failed";
   }
   try {
     System.err.println("Application Locked");
     Thread.sleep(10000);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
     lock.unlock();
   }
   return "success";
 }
```

Comment: Dont do this controller level. Do it service level. That is also based on what kind of operation you are trying to lock is matter.

Comment: Assume it's login functionality. At a time only one person can only log in, If that moment tried any others we need to give a response back ' It's already using' But we can't lock the table. If we have any other ways?